# Mysql query WHERE column is in json array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have setup an query where it selects multiple things.

```
$stm = $db->query('SELECT startUser, forUser, percentage, time, taskTitle, taskDesc, color FROM admin_task WHERE forUser = "'.$queryanswer.'")');
```

But for user is like this in the DB:

```
["demo","   user"]
```

How can I check if forUser (the json array above) has demo? can i even check this?

Comment: This isnt ideal to put json in the db, unless the tool is meant for it for example `mongodb`

Comment: It might not be "ideal," but serializing data in a SQL db is a pretty common practice.

Comment: yes, but if you need to access individual bits of data inside the serialized block,then your DB design is bad and shouldn't have had the data serialized in the first place.... or at least use a DB that understands that json natively.

Comment: Ok, but whats else out there to use. What if there are 8 users involved, what can array them into a db?

Answer (score 26):

I think you can achieve this only in Mysql 5.7.

In version 5.7 you can do something like:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_field, '$.name');
```

and it will extract only the *name key* from json object.

**Search all items with the 'JavaScript' tag:**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json_field, '["JavaScript"]');
```

**Find all items with tags starting 'Java':**

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(json_field, 'one', 'Java%') IS NOT NULL;
```

use 'one' to find the first match or 'all' to find all matches

**You can extract the Twitter nickname using a JSON path:**

```
SELECT name, json_field->"$.twitter" AS `twitter` FROM `user`;
```

**You can also reference a JSON path in the WHERE clause to only return users with a Twitter account:**

```
SELECT name, profile->"$.twitter" AS `twitter` FROM `user` WHERE profile->"$.twitter" IS NOT NULL;
```

You can do more things like:

- Creating JSON Values
- Normalization, Merging, and Autowrapping of JSON Values
- Searching and Modifying JSON Values
- Comparison and Ordering of JSON Values
- Aggregation of JSON Values

for more info please refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Answer (score 4):

If it truly is a JSON field, in 5.7 you can do this:

```
SELECT
  startUser,
  forUser,
  percentage,
  time,
  taskTitle,
  taskDesc,
  color
FROM admin_task
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(forUser->'$[*]', JSON_ARRAY("somestring"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT startUser, 
forUser, 
percentage, 
time, 
taskTitle, 
taskDesc, 
color 
FROM admin_task WHERE JSON_SEARCH(forUser -> '$[*]', 'one', 'demo');
```

Comment: adding some comments to explain why/how it works will inrease the long-term value of the answer